# Disappear HUD bar in espresso android

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have this espresso test in android and I need to wait for the HUD loading bar to disappear(I comment in the place the HUD appear)

```
 onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.editText_username))
            .perform(typeText(loginText), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.editText_password))
            .perform(typeText(passwordText), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.button_login)).perform(click());

mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);

onView(withId(R.id.button_connectToVsm)).perform(click());

mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);

onView(withText("VSM-FB9A")).perform(click());

mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);

**//Now I want to wait for the HUD bar(that occurs after the click) to disappear**
```

Comment: Kindly what does HUD stand for?

Comment: in iOS there is a private view http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIProgressHUD which has a circular ProgressBar and some text. What I don't understand is that if there is an animation like a ProgressBar which is shown espresso should wait for it to finish before continuing the test so this wait should be done automatically by espresso

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can try: 1) add a testing-configuration on your `VSM-FB9A` button so that in testing-mode it doesn't actually put up the HUD view, then you do not have to wait for it. 2) Can you *see* the HUD view in Espresso (like, with `onView(withId(R.id.HUD)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`? If so, you can loop with a sleep until it is no longer displayed.

It is hard to tell what you are testing from you post, but in general I try to break the logic down and test small parts - so that if pressing a button causes a service-call or something before it updates the UI I make it skip the service call and fake the response, so that in my UI tests I just test that the UI behaves correctly. The end-to-end tests can check the service interactions...